# How to bind multiple textboxes in MVC and store it in database?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have five textboxes as of companyName,year,empname,email,phoneno. for these textboxes i ve created a table with the same fields. now i want to bind (empname,email,phone) with (companyname and year)...

Consider in a same company, some three employees are there.i want to store like

Company        Year

HCL            2017

```
      xxxx r@gmail.com 8446565
      yyyy y@gmail.com 7856566
      zzzz z@gmail.com 5465565
```

how can i bind these textboxes and store it in DB?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create a table for company like

```
Id
CompanyName
Year
```

and another table for employees like

```
Id
CompanyId
empname
email
phone
```

CompanyId is the Id(primary key of table company).it will reduce the data redundancy.